# BigQuery Scheduled query (script) loop: needs destination table to be saved, but run fails because of set destination table

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

I had a scheduled query that did not have a destination table set, as it is created in the script with the create table command (in my understanding that is called a script in the BQ environment).
I had to modify the script a bit - which did  not affect the create part, and I wanted to update the existing scheduled query with the modified version.

However I could only update the scheduled query if I gave a destination table (otherwise the Update button is inactive): "A destination table is required to save scheduled query options.". So I saved it with defining a "destination table".

When running the scheduled query later, I got the following error: "Invalid value: configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts; JobID: ..."

For me it seems that I cannot save the scheduled query without a destination table, and I cannot run it with a destination table.

It seems like a catch 22, am I missing something here? How could this script/scheduled query be updated and run?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're on the "preview UI", click from the "SQL workspace" page the top button "HIDE PREVIEW FEATURES" to switch back to regular UI, it may solve the problem.

Comment: @YunZhang thanks, that was the problem! I turned off the preview features, and although I still could not remove the destination table, but I recreated the schedule altogether.

Comment: this fixed my problem, too. it appears you cannot effectively schedule DML scripts with the new UI because the scheduler requires a destination table.

Comment: I am now experiencing the issue as described above, despite having previous created SQL scripts which are scheduled with no destination table (in the new UI). To switch to the old UI, you now have to select "Disable editor tabs"

Comment: 2024 checking in. This still seems to be a problem. The bq command-line tool even dies after specifying a query/script to schedule without a destination table set. Pretty incredible.

Answer (score 1):

Yun Zhang's comment above is the solution:

> If you're on the "preview UI", click from the "SQL workspace" page the
> top button "HIDE PREVIEW FEATURES" to switch back to regular UI, it
> may solve the problem.

Currently, it's necessary to click "Disable editor tabs" to switch back to the old UI.

In my case, I had the same issue as described by the OP (script, no destination table needed but creating a scheduled query required one). After switching off the editor tabs, I was able to make a new scheduled query without having to enter a destination table.